# group oaction of $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, group-actions

Let $A · v = Av\ $ be an action of  group   $\ GL(n, \mathbb{R})$ on $\ \mathbb{R}^n.$

I want to prove that there are only two orbits, the trivial one ${0}$ and ${\mathbb{R}^n}.$ It looks like a "surjectivity check", but I do not know how to choose $A$.

Comment: Hint: basis extension theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $v,w\in\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\}$ then complete each to a basis (their singletons are independent sets):
$v\in\mathcal{B},w\in\mathcal{C}$. Then there exists a unique $\varphi:\mathbb{R}^n\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\varphi(\mathcal{B})=\mathcal{C}$ w.r.t. their order. Here you have $\varphi(v)=w$. Actually you are proving the transitivity of the action on the nonzero vectors, but the linear extension theorem states a sort of $n$-transitivity (given the linear indipendence).